# Unable to delete a firestore doc by id from angular app page

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to delete a firestore doc by id from my angular webapp but unable to do so.

**.ts file**

```
deleteStory(docId)
{
  console.log("Doc id :", +docId);
  this.storiesRef.doc(docId).delete().then(function() {
    console.log("Document successfully deleted!");
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.error("Error removing document: ", error);
  });
}

  ngOnInit() {
    const container = document.getElementById('container');

    this.afs.collection('stories', ref => ref.where('userid', '==', this.userId))
      .get().toPromise()
      .then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
          var date = doc.data() && doc.data().time && doc.data().time.toDate();

          //Create a card element
          const card = document.createElement('div');
          //  card.classList.add('card-body');
          //Construct card content
          const content = ` 

                  <div data-parent="#storycontainer" style="width: 27rem;" class ="mx-auto mb-3">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">

                        <h5 class="card-title">${doc.data().storytitle}</h5>

                    <audio _ngcontent-cjb-c49="" controls="">
                      <source _ngcontent-cjb-c49="" type="audio/webm"
                        src=${doc.data().readyfilepath}>
                      </audio>
                      <p class ="text-sm-left">${date}</p>
                      <button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="deleteStory(${doc.id})">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-record"></span>Delete
                      </button>
                
                      </div>
                      </div>                
                  </div>
                
                  `;
          // Append newyly created card element to the container
          container.innerHTML += content;
```

I see no error in browser console when I click on the html button. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: are you getting Doc id in console while clicking on the button.?!

Comment: No, surprisingly I am not getting it printed in the console.

Comment: There is some mistake in your html code,you have to share some more codes to understand your problem

Comment: thanks pepe, I've updated the .ts code. Actually I am creating the html button from within the .ts component.

Comment: You cannot set inner html and use the angular output events like (click), use angular templates

Comment: why you creating html element from ts file?

Comment: I am new to angular and firestore. I am creating html element from ts file because I wanted to display all the docs the logged in user has created, which is why I printed that inside the snapshot.forEach(doc =>. I know this may not be the proper way but I'd appreciate if I get some help achieving the same in angular template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, I did some search online and following code helped me...

.ts

```
      <button class="btn btn-secondary rounded-circle" (click)="delete(story.payload.doc.id)">
        <span class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </button>
```

.html

```
delete(id: string){
  this.storiesService.deleteStory(id)
  .then(
    res => {
      this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
    },
    err => {
      console.log(err);
    }
  )
}

}
```